# Will spending coins on Club Nintendo affect my balance towards Platinum?

Tags: club-nintendo

I have 310 points on Club Nintendo, and therefore I am a Gold member. The website says:

> *Within each Club Nintendo year (July 1-June 30), earn 300 Coins to reach Gold status or 600 Coins for Platinum status. We add up the Coins you've earned and we don't subtract the Coins you've spent, so you can use your Coins to redeem cool Rewards throughout the year!*

Does this mean that I can spend points on things and not have my existing balance subtracted? Also, if I reach platinum where can I claim the special rewards they give out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, this is how it works. WHen you redeem a Club Nintendo code, the amount of coins you receive is added to the amount of coins you have previously redeemed. This does **not** mean that you can continue purchasing rewards without spending any coins. As you continue to add up, there will be a "count" as to how many coins you have collected over the "Club Nintendo year." This is know as the **Coin Bank**. No amount will be deducted for purchasing merchandise.

If you have already claimed your reward for the Gold status, you should already know how this works. Right before the Club Nintendo year ends, be sure to log in. When you do, there should be a list of the rewards you can receive. Choose carefully, though. You only get to pick one!

I hope this answer has cleared all confusion with this topic! If not, you can always go on the [Club Nintendo Support Page](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2070/p/52) for more details and support with any other question you have. The link will take you to the *Coins and Rewards Overview* section of the page. Once again, I hope this helped!

Comment: consider pressing the check on this question if it completely answers the question! :)

Comment: That's a pretty drawn out way to simply say, Yes. -- Points are cumulative over the year and Gold/Platnum status is just an indicator of how many you have earned for the year.

Comment: So a few followup questions: When does the Nintendo year end, and are the points reset at the end of that year?

Comment: @Someone Just as you asked in your question, the Club Nintendo year ends June 30. The points you earn are reset at the end, and the status is wiped so you can regain the status.

Answer (score -2):

no it does not affect your platinum/gold status.